# How do I check a range where the higher value is dynamic in C#?

Tags: c#, range, comparison

The program im writing currently I need to check if the year given by the user is within a certain range. The bottom value is a fixed value, but the top of this range should be capped at the current year and update itself whenever we enter a new year. I have tried using DateTime.Now.Year assigned to an int value for comparison, but range can't compare non static values.

```
[Range(1900, 2022, ErrorMessage = "Property built before 1900.")]
```

Above is the line in question. Any advice?

Comment: use a custom validator

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with an attribute. Attributes must use constant values. You could either validate the data within the method or just use a minimum value (since that seems to be a constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `RangeAttribute` for this task as it only works with constant values for min/max.

But you can make custom validation attribute for this task. Something like

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class YearRangeAttribute : RangeAttribute
{
    public YearRangeAttribute(int minimum) : base(minimum, DateTime.Now.Year)
    {
    }
}
```

Here we hide the `maximum` value from constructor and internally set it to the current year. In other aspects our new attribute works as a normal `RangeAttribute`.

The problem here is that is `maximimum` is fixed at the moment when attribute instance is created. So, if you start a program at Dec 31, then you will have a problem after 24 hours of runtime as the real year will be changed, but your `maximum` will not.

Unfortunately, the `Maximum` property of `RangeAttribute` is not virtual so you can't override it.

This problem may be solved with custom attribte not inhernited from `RangeAttribute`, but from `ValidationAttribute`. Then you can reimplement the logic of `RangeAttribute` (sources available [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/RangeAttribute.cs)). You can throw out the most part of reference implementation and implement all logic only for `int`.